# Plot Correlation Table imported from excel with Python

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn

So I am trying to plot correlation Matrix (already calculated) in python. the table is like below:
[image]

And I would like it to look like this:

[image]

I am using the Following code in python:

```
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd

data =pd.read_excel('/Desktop/wetchimp_global/corr/correlation_matrix.xlsx')

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)

corrMatrix = data.corr()
print (corrMatrix)

sn.heatmap(corrMatrix, annot=True)
plt.show()
```

Note that, the matrix is ready and I don't want to calculate the correlation again! but I failed to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you directly input the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted to frist column (names) and add them later so the code is as below:

```
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data =pd.read_excel('/Users/yousefalbuhaisi/Desktop/wetchimp_global/corr/correlation_matrix.xlsx')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=150)
y_axis_labels = ['CLC','GIEMS','GLWD','LPX_BERN','LPJ_WSL','LPJ_WHyME','SDGVM','DLEM','ORCHIDEE','CLM4ME']

sn.heatmap(data,yticklabels=y_axis_labels, annot=True)
plt.show()
```

and the results are:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are recalculating the correlation with the following line:

```
corrMatrix = data.corr()
```

You then go on to utilize this recalculated variable in the heatmap here:

```
sn.heatmap(corrMatrix, annot=True)
plt.show()
```

To resolve this, instead of passing in the `corrMatrix` value which is the recalculated value, pass the pure excel data `data` or `df` (as df is just a copy of data). Thus, all the code you should need is:

```
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd

data =pd.read_excel('/Desktop/wetchimp_global/corr/correlation_matrix.xlsx')
sn.heatmap(data, annot=True)
plt.show()
```

Note that this assumes, however, that your data IS ready for the heatmap as you suggest. As we online do not have access to your data we cannot confirm that.

Comment: I have tried that. I got this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'CLC'.